# How to detect that a C/C++ file is using windows specific stuff

Tags: c++, c, testing, testsuite

Basically I want to test files/libraries/code in general that wont run on Linux by detecting windows specific includes, program calls, dynamically linked libraries at runtime, anything that isn't Linux compatible.
This is to make sure that the resulting program always works under Linux.
I also have to automate this

Thanks!

Comment: WOW that is going to be one massive list I think, good luck.

Comment: This may be more suitable at Stack Overflow.

Comment: You could "cheat" by actually performing the compilation and seeing if you get an error.  That's how things like `autoconf` used to test if a library existed, etc. -- it actually performed a test compilation.